# ManagementEventWatcher и Console.ReadLine()

Tags: c#

Есть нижеприведенный класс:

```
public static void ProcessWatch_Initialize()
{
    try
    {
        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("root\\CIMV2");
        scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = true;

        WqlEventQuery query = new WqlEventQuery("Select * From __InstanceCreationEvent Within 1 Where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_DiskDrive'");
        watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(scope, query);
        watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(watcher_EventArrived);
        watcher.Start();

        Console.ReadLine();


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (watcher != null)
            watcher.Stop();
    }
}
```

Все как бы работает и все замечательно, но, есть одно но, если убрать `Console.ReadLine()` после запуска `watcher`, то код перестает работать? Как с этим бороться?

Answer (score 2):

В принципе логично. Если убрать `Console.ReadLine();`, то сначала выполнится блок `try`, который запустит `watcher`, а потом блок `finally`, который его остановит, т.к. выполнится в любом случае.

Можно попробовать так:

```
try
{
    // тут код с запуском watcher
    while (Console.ReadLine() != "stop")
    {
    }

    watcher.Stop();
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
     if (watcher != null)
         watcher.Stop();
     Console.ReadKey();
 }
```

Пока не введем слово `stop`, `watcher` будет продолжать работать.

Comment: Если честно, то я не знал или даже не так предполагал назначение элемента finally.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась следующим образом: пришлось добавить `return;` после  `watcher.Start();`

а так же удалить

```
finally
{
    if (watcher != null)
        watcher.Stop();
}
```